# How can I check if the player is the collider that triggered the enemy colliders? With multiple triggers on the enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I am trying to add 2 colliders onto my enemy game object. One for the vison range and one for the attack range. I have two scripts that work together to check if the collider has been triggered. One generic detector script that is just used to run an event if the trigger is entered. and then my main enemy script.

player is assigned as public GameObject player

```
`public void OnVisionTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnVisionTriggerEnter");
        if(other.tag == player.tag)
        {    
            Debug.Log("OnVisionTriggerEnter");
            if (other == player.GetComponent<Collider2D>())
            {
                Debug.Log("OnVisionTriggerEnter");
                isFollowing = true;
            }
        }
    }`
```

This is my trouble block right now. Neither of the if statements will pass but the function as a whole is running. I'm at a loss of what to do

I tried multiple different ways to check if the game object that entered the trigger was the player including:
as it's written
`GameObect test = other.gameObject;`
`if(other.gameObject == player)`

If the "if" statement would pass the rest of the code works fine.

Comment: Its important to know which object the collider is on.  The gameObject in `other.gameObject` is the object the collider is attached to.  If the collider is on a child object, that equals comparison would fail.  Try logging the name of the object who entered the trigger, and possibly the root object name as well.

Comment: Try using the debug log to print out the tag on collision, so you know what it returns.

Comment: [Debug your code!](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) set breakpoints and check what exactly you are colliding with ... alternatively as mentioned **log** .. for instance e.g. `Debug.Log($"{nameof(OnVisionTriggerEnter)}: other = \"{other}\" with tag = \"{other.tag}\"", this);`

Comment: in general if there is the possibility of nested colliders etc rather go by a dedicated `Player` component (`MonoBehaviour`) and use `other.GetComponentInParent<Player>()` so you always check whether that collider is attached to the player or any of its children

Comment: Thanks all, I ended up asking ChatGPT because I'm impatient and it told me to make child game objects and assign each one it's own script with OnTriggerEnter2D instead of using unity events